# How can I SSH locally into a server that is using a VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn

How can i access locally through ssh to my orange pi that is running under a vpn provider?
I attach a draw how it is build the infrastructure, it's a simple hose connection.
The orange pi has a static ip, and it has ufw enabled, the only ip allowed to access is the static ip of my computer.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev6aZ.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few steps to get you going. Make sure that your Orange Pi is connected to the VPN provider and has an active VPN connection. Verify this by checking the VPN status on the Orange Pi.Determine the internal IP address of your Orange Pi within the VPN network. This is the IP you will use to connect to the Orange Pi locally.

If you have access to your router, you'll need to configure port forwarding to allow SSH traffic to reach the Orange Pi. Forward incoming SSH requests on the router to the internal IP of the Orange Pi, using the SSH port (default: 22). Refer to your router's documentation for instructions on how to set up port forwarding. Ensure that your Orange Pi's ufw firewall is properly configured to allow SSH connections from your computer's static IP. You can do this by adding a rule to allow incoming SSH traffic from your computer's IP address.

For example, on the Orange Pi, run the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow from <your_computer_static_ip> to any port 22
```

With the VPN connected, port forwarding configured, and ufw allowing SSH traffic from your computer's IP, you should be able to SSH into the Orange Pi. Open your terminal or SSH client on your computer and enter the following command:

```
ssh <orange_pi_internal_ip>
```

If the setup is correct, you should be prompted for the username and password of the Orange Pi. Enter the credentials to establish the SSH connection.

If you encounter any issues during the process, ensure that the VPN connection is stable, port forwarding is correctly configured, and the ufw firewall rules are properly set up. Additionally, double-check that your computer's static IP address is correctly configured in the ufw firewall rules.